# How to add custom panel in page XAML for UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I make a custom panel that look like this:

```
 public class CustomPanel : Panel
 { 
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
      ...
    }  
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

In my project I have the file CustomPanel.cs.
Now I want to be able to place this custom panel in my MainPage.xaml, like this:

```
<Page x:Class="CustomPanelProject.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:CustomPanelProject.Views"
      xmlns:control="using:CustomPanelProject.Controls"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            Orientation="Vertical">
    <control:CustomPanel>

    </control:CustomPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

So I thought this approach will work, but the designer keep showing this error message:

> The name "CustomPanel" does not exist in the namespace "using:CustomPanelProject.Controls".

What am I missing? Maybe the panel should have a related xaml file like the user controls?

Comment: Are you sure that your CustomPanel class is actually declared in namespace `CustomPanelProject.Controls`?

Comment: The fact that designer is complaining about this panel doesn't always mean that there is something wrong about it. Did you try to build or run your project? Sometimes it's necessary for refreshing designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I was having problems with the name of my namespace. So my namespace was misspelled. Very stupid mistake.

Comment: Happens to even the best of us, +1